# Perform basic operations (add, subtract, multiply and divide) on every row of a Matrix by a single entry of a vector

Tags: r

I'm trying to use a fast enough solution (*and avoid loops*) for the following problem:
I have a matrix nxn (square but not necessarily) and a vector or size nx1. I want to divide every row of the matrix by the reciprocal element in the vector as follows:

- First row should be divided by the 1st vector element,
- Second row should be divided by the 2nd vector element,
- .
- .
- .
- Nth row should be divided by the n-th vector element.

  stats = matrix(1.2,10000,10000)

the same for the vector, which is of size let's say 10,000 and initialized to some values.

Answer (score 2):

This is what the `sweep` function is for

```
mm <- matrix(rep(1:5, 7), ncol=7)
d <- 1:5
sweep(mm, 1, d, "/")
```

Here we tell sweep that for every row of `mm` (for MARGIN 1=rows, 2=columns) divide out the corresponding value from `d`

Comment: or `mm / d[row(mm)]`

Answer (score 0):

Could you just divide the matrix by the vector?

```
m <- matrix(1:20, nrow=5)
#[,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    6   11   16
#[2,]    2    7   12   17
#[3,]    3    8   13   18
#[4,]    4    9   14   19
#[5,]    5   10   15   20

v <- 5:1
#[1] 5 4 3 2 1

#Divide matrix row 1 by 5 (v[1])
#Divide matrix row 2 by 4 (v[2])
m/v
#[,1]      [,2]      [,3]  [,4]
#[1,]  0.2  1.200000  2.200000  3.20
#[2,]  0.5  1.750000  3.000000  4.25
#[3,]  1.0  2.666667  4.333333  6.00
#[4,]  2.0  4.500000  7.000000  9.50
#[5,]  5.0 10.000000 15.000000 20.00
```

(Sidenote: for dividing by columns, you'd have to transpose the matrix)